# How can I set a default value on a groovy template expansion?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to expand properties with groovy.

I put following into my `build.gradle`.

```
processResources {
    expand(project.properties)
}
```

And here comes my `application.yaml`.

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${uri:'mongodb://x:y@a.b.c.d:27017,a.b.c.e:27017/'}
```

My intention is that

- when `uri` switch provided use it.

  - `gradle -Puri=xyz`

    - `uri: xyz`
- else use the default value(`mongodb://x:y@...`)

  - `gradle ...`

    - `uri: mongodb...`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Define the default value in a `gradle.properties` file like so:

```
uri=mongodb://x:y@a.b.c.d:27017,a.b.c.e:27017/
```